# R: Error in device(...) : cannot open file

Tags: r

I have been using the package Muma for OPLS regression. Everything works fine except for this part of the code: `plsda(scaling="pareto")`

I get an error message:

```
Error in device(...) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/Julia /PLS-DA_pareto/W*cPlot_PLSDA_1Component_pareto.pdf'
```

Could you please help fix the problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You are trying to open a pdf file, are you sure you are using the right function to do it so? If so are you sure you have the rights to read the file? Or that the file is really there under this name?

Comment: Thanks. This function is supposed to save two files in a pdf format. It saves only one and issues this error. I also tried to use this function for a dataset provided in this package Muma and it works. All other functions work well with my dataset and save files in a pdf format with no problem. Therefore, I do not have any clue what might be causing this problem.

Comment: Well, here the error says **open** not save, write or load. But if this function is supposed to save two files which are this two files, I only see 1 argument. But it could also be that the name of this file is not accepted ( I suspect of the *W** part)

Comment: Thanks. From a description:(http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/muma/muma.pdf):

plsda(scaling)

“The number of components to be calculated are defined as the number of classes - 1. A plot reporting pairwise representation of the components is graphically visualized and written in the directory
’PLS-DA’, together with the PLS score and loading matrices."

This function is supposed to make a calculation, save this file and a graph and open the graph, but it did not do it. It only saved PLS score and loading matrices and issued an error, but it works fine with the author’s dataset.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Windows, make sure the pdf you want to write to is not open somewhere. A google search yielded: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/pdf-creation-error-td870753.html.
If the pdf file of the same name I want to run is open when I run

```
pdf(paste('visual_check.pdf',sep = ''), height = 4, width = 15)
```

It gives:

> Error in pdf(paste("visual_check.pdf", sep = ""), height = 4, width = 15) : 
>     cannot open file 'visual_check.pdf'

If the pdf file is not open, it works just fine.

On my old Mac (OS 10.10) this is not an issue and the pdf device will open and the pdf will updated in preview, even if it is open.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds very stupid, but just three-double check that this directory is spelled right and exists. Took my about 30 min to find an extra s somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is simpler... re-run `setwd()`to the directory where you're working. For me it was the solution.